# TupleQueryResultView - Serialization error - Query changes from graphdb using history and versioning plugin

Tags: java, graphdb, rdf4j

I try to query the changes from graphdb using history and versioning plugin (https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/change-tracking.html). This is the query:

```
var additionsQuery =
        repositoryConnection.prepareTupleQuery(
            QueryLanguage.SPARQL,
            "SELECT * FROM <http://www.ontotext.com/added/"
                + transactionId
                + "> {\n"
                + " graph ?g {\n"
                + "     ?s ?p ?o \n"
                + "   }\n"
                + "}");

while (additionsResult.hasNext()) {
      // process result
}
```

The result is quite big (180000 triples) and the query takes very long. After some time it aborts.

The same query works perfectly fine, if I execute it in graphdb workbench console. So it seems like the problem is the api..

The problem only occurs with large deltas, with small deltas everything works perfectly.

Interestingly, a construct query returns an empty result:

```
CONSTRUCT { 
    ?s ?p ?o 
} WHERE { 
    GRAPH http://www.ontotext.com/added/7699fe6e-525d-4cdd-b9a8-8b48d61e468e {
        ?s ?p ?o
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

Set the timeout to very high number, or infinite.

Use multiple small queries and instead of one big query (using SKIP and LIMIT).

Use a fresh and new connection exclusively for this query.

Anyone have a clue?

GraphDB exception:

```
18:23:32.380 [repositories/lakhsbdcsdc] ERROR c.o.graphdb.sesame.CatchHandler - Caught error and log it before check if the responce is committed!
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.TupleQueryResultHandlerException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.handleSolutionImpl(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.AbstractQueryResultWriter.handleSolution(AbstractQueryResultWriter.java:68)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.CatchHandler.processWithBuffer(CatchHandler.java:139)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.TupleQueryResultView.renderInternal(TupleQueryResultView.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.QueryResultView.render(QueryResultView.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at com.ontotext.forest.core.request.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.ThresholdOutputStream.write(ThresholdOutputStream.java:92)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingServletOutputStream.write(CompressingServletOutputStream.java:66)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.writeString(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.writeQName(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.writeValue(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.handleSolutionImpl(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:186)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1360)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:547)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
18:23:32.487 [repositories/lakhsbdcsdc] ERROR c.o.g.sesame.TupleQueryResultView - Serialization error
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.TupleQueryResultHandlerException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.endQueryResult(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:164)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.CatchHandler.processWithBuffer(CatchHandler.java:151)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.TupleQueryResultView.renderInternal(TupleQueryResultView.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.QueryResultView.render(QueryResultView.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at com.ontotext.forest.core.request.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeByte(OutputBuffer.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:80)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.ThresholdOutputStream.write(ThresholdOutputStream.java:60)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingServletOutputStream.write(CompressingServletOutputStream.java:74)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeByte(DataOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.endQueryResult(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:161)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:547)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1360)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:547)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.ThresholdOutputStream.write(ThresholdOutputStream.java:92)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingServletOutputStream.write(CompressingServletOutputStream.java:66)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.writeString(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.writeQName(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.writeValue(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultWriter.handleSolutionImpl(BinaryQueryResultWriter.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.AbstractQueryResultWriter.handleSolution(AbstractQueryResultWriter.java:68)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.CatchHandler.processWithBuffer(CatchHandler.java:139)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Java exception:

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.impl.QueueCursor.convert(QueueCursor.java:58) ~[rdf4j-query-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.impl.QueueCursor.convert(QueueCursor.java:22) ~[rdf4j-query-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.QueueIteration.checkException(QueueIteration.java:165) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.QueueIteration.getNextElement(QueueIteration.java:122) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.LookAheadIteration.lookAhead(LookAheadIteration.java:81) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.LookAheadIteration.hasNext(LookAheadIteration.java:49) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.IterationWrapper.hasNext(IterationWrapper.java:63) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at at.ac.qe.dairy.repo.persistence.RepositoryDao.getAdditions(RepositoryDao.java:143) ~[classes/:na]
    at at.ac.qe.dairy.repo.rpc.observer.PushRequestStreamObserver.onCompleted(PushRequestStreamObserver.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:260) ~[grpc-stub-1.32.1.jar:1.32.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onHalfClose(Contexts.java:86) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:820) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.impl.QueueCursor.convert(QueueCursor.java:58) ~[rdf4j-query-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.impl.QueueCursor.convert(QueueCursor.java:22) ~[rdf4j-query-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.QueueIteration.checkException(QueueIteration.java:165) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.QueueIteration.handleClose(QueueIteration.java:155) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.AbstractCloseableIteration.close(AbstractCloseableIteration.java:63) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.iteration.QueueIteration.checkException(QueueIteration.java:162) ~[rdf4j-util-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-osgi-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-osgi-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:175) ~[httpcore-osgi-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:152) ~[httpcore-osgi-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:118) ~[httpclient-osgi-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:393) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultParser.readQName(BinaryQueryResultParser.java:244) ~[rdf4j-queryresultio-binary-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultParser.parse(BinaryQueryResultParser.java:171) ~[rdf4j-queryresultio-binary-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.AbstractTupleQueryResultParser.parseQueryResult(AbstractTupleQueryResultParser.java:48) ~[rdf4j-queryresultio-api-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.helpers.BackgroundTupleResult.run(BackgroundTupleResult.java:89) ~[rdf4j-queryresultio-api-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.client.BackgroundResultExecutor.lambda$autoCloseRunnable$0(BackgroundResultExecutor.java:65) ~[rdf4j-http-client-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you resolved this?